# CollectionView Pagination Issue

Tags: ios, swift, pagination

This line of code is supposed to fire off a new pagination request once I scroll. However it always hits the else statement

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.item >= allEvents.count - 1 {
            // print("paginating for post")
            paginationHelper.paginate(completion: { [unowned self] (events) in
                self.allEvents.append(contentsOf: events)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                }
            })
        }else{
            print("Not paginating")
        }
    }
```

Any idea on what could be going wrong?

Comment: Please visit [this](https://github.com/mukeshlokare/CollectionViewDemo) check if it is working for you

Comment: well I am scrolling vertically @mukesh_lokare

Comment: Yes it has same functionality forget that aspect ratio which i did in the demo

Comment: @mukesh_lokare I downloaded the file and it is empty

Comment: hey wait i think i forget to push new changes

Comment: check now i have pushed latest changes

Comment: ok I  will do @mukesh_lokare

Comment: okay so what am I addding again your collectionview implementation is blank @mukesh_lokare